# Bunch of Error While Importing Android Project to Eclipse, New Learner

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I would like to start my journey in learning Android programming. And from my experience before, I'd love to, and comfortable with learning by doing. I meant, I chose to familiarize myself with the environment by looking at the successful project rather than learn java programming one by one, and start from there I will start dive deep from tutorial and action so I can rapidly learn it.

But this Android seems not friendly enough since our first meet. After downloading and familiarize with the button, I tried to import existing android project available on internet and it appears like in the screenshot.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/euqvcg9hnljfcfc/bnbb.PNG?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dlpxwt2i6p38ceg/cncc.png?dl=0

After been overwhelming with questions, there still many question that still unanswered. I don't even know what SDK for, what ADT, how to upload from google play service, also I DON'T EVEN SEEN (the code part) loaded succesfully, yet.

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated!
Thanks.

**[UPDATE 5/14/16]**
In the screenshot I opened two projects, one of them return an error from AndroidManifest.xml, so here's the file:
https://www[.]dropbox[.]com/s/m0buzvot4z53ps9/AndroidManifest.xml?dl=0

The second project, error message said right at 'Unable to resolve target andorid-18' and all the way down.
https://www[.]dropbox[.]com/s/77trdg01occs2te/styles.xml?dl=0

For anyone who think it's problem with outdated android SDK, I can make it sure if it's been updated to last version. Take a look at this:
https://www[.]dropbox[.]com/s/rilf0xh1mnsxrbs/sdk-see.PNG?dl=0

Remove those '[' and ']' char as I am not allowed to place more than 2 links at the same time (my reputation is still below 10).

Comment: Update you Android SDK

Comment: Suggest you to start using android studio. From the screenshot main error is in AndroidManifest.xml file. As adviced by dixit please update the Android API to v23 from the SDK manager if that also does not helps then please add android manifest file to the question.

Comment: @[Dixit Panchal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4566531/dixit-panchal) @[Shadow Droid](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3983066/shadow-droid) Hi thanks for your quick response. See mine, I thought it was in latest version of Android SDK :(

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rilf0xh1mnsxrbs/sdk-see.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for the Android Development tool (ADT) in Eclipse has Ended.
So Migrate or New create your app development projects to android studio.

Comment: I want to learn Eclipse first sir. I thought Eclipse user aren't all changed the way they code to Android Studio (browse them too!). Means, Eclipse must be able to be used. Thanks anyway for response